# Married couple problem for circular table, not exactly menage problem

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we arrange n married couples around a circular
table so that no person is next to her (his) spouse and no person sits
next to a person of the same sex?

As i see the solution of the meange problem [here](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/menage/menage/menage.html), i found that they are not taking the table as circular. By circular i mean that, if one arrangement can be obtained from other by rotation then they are same.So, i feel that it's not exactly the menage problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Every solution to your problem gives $2n$ solutions to the menage problem.  In your solution, everyone has a unique solution relative to Peter.  In the menage problem, Peter has $2n$ possible seats.
So just divide the Menage solution by $2n$.